# ¿Cómo cambiar la categoría base de un modelo GLM multinomial?

Tags: r, glm

he intentado realizar un modelo probit con una base de datos que cree para practicar:

[image: base]

Para poder realizar un modelo glm es necesario transformar la variable numerica a factor, por lo que realice el cambio así:

```
pruebalevels$estrato=factor(pruebalevels$estrato,levels = c(0:2),labels = c("bajo","medio","alto"))
```

pruebalevels$ingreso=factor(pruebalevels$ingreso,levels = c(0:2),labels = c("bajo","medio","alto"))

Como puede observarse, ahora la base esta convertida en factor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente realizo la estimacion del modelo multinomial probit así:

```
multinomial=multinom(estrato~ingreso,data = pruebalevels,family =multinom(link = "probit"))
```

y obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora, automáticamente se toma el valor de 0(bajo) tanto para ingreso como para estrato por ser el menor nivel como la base, es decir que el modelo toma como referencia a los individuos que tienen bajo estrato y bajo ingreso. De esta forma el modelo estima para medio y alto. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo cambiar la base de referencia que utiliza el modelo, de tal forma que pueda indicar que categoría quiero que tome como referencia tanto para la variable dependiente como para la independiente ? Por ejemplo: quiero que tome como categoria base en estrato e ingreso la categoria "medio", de esta manera podré estimar coeficientes para "bajo" y "alto" muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar las categoría de referencia tienes que usar la función `relevel()`. Pero primero te mostraré como darte cuenta cual es tu categoría de referencia. Para eso usamos la función `contrasts()`.

Primero para la variable estrato.

```
contrasts(df$estrato)
      MEDIO ALTO
BAJO      0    0
MEDIO     1    0
ALTO      0    1
```

Y para la variable ingreso.

```
contrasts(df$ingreso)
      MEDIO ALTO
BAJO      0    0
MEDIO     1    0
ALTO      0    1
```

como puedes ver, la categoría `BAJO` en los dos factores es la referencia. Entonces si tu quieres cambiar la referencia a `MEDIO`, tendrías que hacerlo con la función `relevel()`.

```
df$estrato<-relevel(df$estrato, ref = "MEDIO")
df$ingreso<-relevel(df$ingreso, ref = "MEDIO")
```

Entonces ahora ya puedes correr tu modelo multiprobit.

```
multinomial<-multinom(estrato~ingreso,data = df,
                     family =multinom(link = "probit")
```

Los resultados serían:

```
Call:
multinom(formula = estrato ~ ingreso, data = df, family = multinom(link = "probit"))

Coefficients:
     (Intercept) ingresoBAJO ingresoALTO
BAJO  0.17589681  0.05293471 -0.20979728
ALTO  0.03774079  0.21356547  0.05757015

Residual Deviance: 656.8856 
AIC: 668.8856
```

**NOTA:** los resultados de la regresión me salen distintos porque no conozco tu data frame, así que cree uno aleatorio. Es así que mi data frame se llama `df` y no como el tuyo `pruevalevels`

Comment: acabo de seguir tu guía, y practicando encontré que también es posible realizar el cambio de base sin necesidad de sobrescribir la base de datos al usar la funcion relevel() dentro de la función multinom, así:

multinomial1=multinom(relevel(pruebalevels$estrato, ref = "medio")~relevel(pruebalevels$ingreso, ref = "medio"),data = pruebalevels,family =multinom(link = "logit"))

Comment: Claro. No hay ningún problema. Pero lo mejor es cambiarlo y tener un código más limpio. Por que si tienes que hacer otra regresión tendrías que volver a referenciar la categoría base.